# How to get data from HTML data attributes into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have to upload some data with form load, to be used in JavaScript operations on the page. I am uploading the data like below:

```html
<select id="allrecords">
    <option data-s-type="X" data-n-type="9" value="xxx">xxx</option>
    <option data-s-type="X" data-n-type="9" value="lmn">lmn</option>
    <option data-s-type="X" data-n-type="8" value="xyz">xyz</option>
    <option data-s-type="Y" data-n-type="3" value="zzz">zzz</option>
    ...
</select>
```

From this data, data-s-type and data-n-type properties are used in finding out which values will be added to an array, which is later being used in the program. I am not able to think of a way to get that array using this select list.

e.g. when `data-s-type="X"` AND `data-n-type=9`, `array = [xxx,lmn]`

I don't have to upload data as hidden select list.

Comment: Is it missing a `multiple` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.map` creates arrays, and inside the function you check for the values you'd like, and if they match you return the elements value to the array, like so:

```
var arr = $.map($('#allrecords option'), function(el,i) {
    if ($(el).data('s-type') == 'X' && $(el).data('n-type') == '9') 
      return el.value;
});

arr //is now ['xxx', 'lmn']
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sR3Ag/)

Comment: thx, this works. but what if i do not want to use a select option to store data? I have key value pairs in a hash. how can i put them in a, say, DIV element and then obtain a certain value based on a key value?

Comment: @rajeev - you can use $.map to create arrays based on almost anything, so that should'nt be a problem. For hashes you'd somehow need to get those hashes and filter them with something in the $.map function, but what and how is hard to answer without seeing the code, and you'd probably be better of by asking a new question regarding that, with some code etc.